# How can I export a lidR LAScatalog to a shapefile?

Tags: r, lidr

I would like to export a lascatalog to a shapefile. It could be done in the past with rgdal but this is being retired.

The error is below.

```r
library(lidR)
library(sf)
ctg <- readLAScatalog(system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR"))
st_write(as(ctg, "sf"), "ctgIndex.shp")
#> Error in as(ctg, "sf") : 
#>  no method or default for coercing “LAScatalog” to “sf”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sf::st_as_sf` instead of `as(ctg, "sf")` before to write with `sf::st_write`

Note: `sf::st_as_sf` simply returns `ctg@data` which IS an `sf` object.

Comment: that works thanks; the complete line would be:    sf::st_write(sf::st_as_sf(ctg), "ctgIndex.shp")